# FAPI Fivestar settings in custom form

Tags: 7, forms

I have a multistep form with [mforms](https://www.drupal.org/project/mforms) in forth step my form have fivestar field from a review node content type. 
All fivestar field display option are set to basic, but fields are displaying differently.

I tried to change the display widget in my module, with no luck. If i try to change the widget it returns to defaults.

Any suggestion are welcome. thx

```
function _reviewform_step4(&$form_state, &$next_step, $params) {

    $form = array();

    //attaching existing content type fields
    $review = new stdClass();
    $review->type = 'review'; //content type

    field_attach_form('node', $review, $form, $form_state);

    foreach ($form_state['field'] as $field) {
        if ($field['und']['field']['type'] == 'fivestar') {
            $field_name = $field['und']['field']['field_name'];
            // not working
            $form[$field_name]['und'][0]['rating']['#settings']['widget']['name'] = 'flames';
            $form[$field_name]['und'][0]['rating']['#settings']['widget']['css'] =     'sites/all/modules/fivestar/widgets/flames/flames.css';    
            // not working to
            $form[$field_name]['und'][0]['rating']['#widget']['name'] = 'flames';
            $form[$field_name]['und'][0]['rating']['#widget']['css'] = 'sites/all/modules/fivestar/widgets/flames/flames.css';    
        }
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i used another concept. Instead of attaching all field with `field_attach_form()` i used

`field_info_field()`, `field_info_instance()` and  `field_default_form()` to attache field one by one. Here i could override the instance widget settings.

```
 $rel_field = field_info_field('field_reliability');
 $rel_instance = field_info_instance('node', 'field_reliability', 'review');

 $rel_instance['widget']['settings']['widget']['fivestar_widget'] = drupal_get_path('module', 'fivestar') . 'widgets/flames/flames.css';

 $my_reliability = field_default_form('node', $review, $rel_field, $rel_instance, LANGUAGE_NONE, array(), $form, $form_state);
 $form['field_reliability'] = $my_reliability;
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with mforms, but I see a few potential issues:

1)  your form doesn't have a standard signature ($form, &$form_state, ...).  I obviously can't see how you're calling it, but this is not a typical thing to do.

2)  when getting the path of the css, you should be using drupal_get_path
https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#attached

3)  widget is not a property of #settings

Comment: 1) mforms use this signature
2) Your right, but this is a debug/demo code
3) thx

Thanks for your efforts.